# phpmailer script on godaddy is not working

Tags: email, server, phpmailer, shared-hosting, fault

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) 2017-11-15 13:11:07    SMTP connect() failed.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available <br/>";

$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['phone'];
$client = $_POST['client'];

$to = 'myemailid@gmail.com';
$subject = 'user registration';
$phone = "phone number:".$number;
$message = "client details:"."\n"."email:".$email."\n"."phone number:".$number."\n"."client:".$client;
$headers = "From:".$email;

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'hosting.secureserver.net';       //  ssl://smtp.gmail.com          // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '';                      // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '';                    // SMTP password

$mail->From = 'myemailid@gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'none';  //TLS                      // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;          //587                          // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom($email);
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;

if($mail->send()) {
    header("Location: ../../thankyou.html");
}
else {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    //header("Location: ../../error.html");
}
?>
```

this is the error i am receiving, as i am new to this php any detailed explanation would be highly appreciated. thank you

Comment: Search before you post. GoDaddy has very strict rules on outbound email; they have come up on here many times, and are mentioned in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide that is linked from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The host `hosting.secureserver.net` does not exist. You need to set the correct server and credentials for the outbound SMTP server. This information should be provided by whoever is hosting your email services - probably your web host.

Comment: tried it but no luck

Comment: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2017-11-15 15:04:28 SMTP connect() failed. still getting this error